# If .NET uses mark&sweep GC, why does it cut the memory addresses space in half?

Tags: .net, garbage-collection

According to MSDN, the .NET framework [uses the mark&sweep garbage collection method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088.aspx#what_happens_during_a_garbage_collection). The same page also says that [on 32bit systems, the address space is 2GB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088.aspx#fundamentals_of_memory) - which means that the address space is cut in half from the 4GB of 32bit systems.

Cutting the available memory in half is a trait of the stop&copy garbage collection method, but .NET uses mark&sweep which can operate on the whole address space - so why does .NET cut the address space in half?

Comment: I believe this is a limit from Windows itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is Windows, not .NET.  32bit Windows reserved the top 2GB of the address space for the operating system, and restricted applications to 2GB (provided the /3GB flag wasn't used).

Note that, in practice, it's actually worse.  A 32bit .NET application will typically start raising `OutOfMemoryException` between 1.2 and 1.6GB of RAM usage, even on a 64bit system with plenty of phsyical memory.

Comment: Are those `OutOfMemeoryException`s because of fragmentation of available space, or because of the memory used by the CLR itself?

Comment: @IdanArye I think it's a mix of many factors.  The generational nature + partitioning (ie: SOH vs LOH), fragmentation, CLR usage, etc.